# Error en metodo al mover archivos de un directorio a otro

Tags: java

En un método donde muevo archivos, al pasarle los parámetros y realizar la operación, siempre me aparece un error. Si algo me esta fallando, podrian ayudarme?

```
public void MoverArchivo(String oldPath, String oldName, String newPath) {
    File f = null;
    File f1 = null;
    boolean bool = false;
    try {      
        f = new File(oldPath+oldName);
        f1 = new File(newPath+oldName);

        if(f.renameTo(new File(newPath+oldName))) {
            System.out.println("Archivo removido");
        } else {
            System.out.println("El archivo "+ oldName + " no pudo ser cambiado de destino");
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ADVERTENCIA: El archivo " + oldName + " no pudo ser cambiado de destino, CAUSA:" + e);
    }
    System.out.println("Termina archivo "+oldName);
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------");
}
```

Comment: Podrias indicar que error te da y en que linea, asi es mas facil encontrar una solución

Comment: Por favor indica cuál es el error o excepción que aparece con este método. Te recomiendo que no imprimas `e`, sino `e.printStackTrace`. Quizás no quieras tener 2 buffers de salida: `out` y `error`, así que puedes utilizar esto: `e.printStackTrace(System.out)`

Comment: Siempre me tira el error "El archivo + "nombre del archivo" no pudo ser cambiado.."

Comment: Lo importante es el `e` del `Exception e` y ver el mensaje. Aplica la modificación que te puse en el comentario anterior y edita tu pregunta para que agregues el resultado del stacktrace.

Comment: Podrían fallarte muchas cosas, pero es recomendable siempre agregues el error que marca en tu consola!

Comment: Ni siquiera entra al catch, al parecer el error esta a la hora de usar el metodo renameTo, por que en la consola no me muestra ningun error del catch

Comment: Quizás los valores de `oldPath`, `oldName` y `newPath` no correspondan a archivos o carpetas existentes o que el usuario con el que ejecutas el método no tenga permisos sobre estas rutas. Verifica eso mientras realizas el debug respectivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basado en [tu respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/4228/227), te recomiendo que para evitar problemas con estos casos utilices el constructor [`File(String, String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), el cual abstrae los problemas que tienes al agregar el caracter de separación de carpetas:

De esta manera, tu código:

```
f = new File(oldPath+oldName);
f1 = new File(newPath+oldName);
```

Cambia a:

```
f = new File(oldPath, oldName);
f1 = new File(newPath, oldName);
```

Comment: Soy muy nuevo en esto, gracias por el comentario, me ayudo muchisimo.

Comment: @KevinM. bienvenido a es stackoverflow si alguna de las respuestas ayudo a solucionar tu problema puedes hacer upvote y/o aceptar la que mas creas conveniente, puede haber respuestas que ayuden a solicionar tu pregunta de una forma y otras que la complementen, si crees que ayudan de alguna manera no dudes en, upvote y/o aceptar  puedes mirar este link http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Ya encontré mi error, al parecer, a la hora de asignar el directorio antiguo quedaba concatenada la ultima carpeta con el archivo, haciendo una dirección no valida, por ejemplo:

`Users/soporte02/Desktop/Carpeta1ArchivoEjemplo.pdf`

Lo que tenia que hacer era simplemente concatenarle al asignar el antiguo y nuevo directorio, una doble diagonal `//` para que finalmente quedara así:

`Users/soporte02/Desktop/Carpeta1/ArchivoEjemplo.pdf`

El método ahora quedo así:

```
    public void MoverArchivo(String oldPath, String oldName, String newPath)
    {
        File f = null;
        boolean bool = false;
        try{      
                f = new File(oldPath + "//" + oldName);

                if(f.renameTo(new File(newPath+ "//" + oldName)))
                {
                    System.out.println("Archivo reubicado");
                }
                    else
                {
                    System.out.println("El archivo "+ oldName + " no pudo ser cambiado de destino");
                }
            }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }
```

Este método lo uso en un ciclo para mover todos los archivos únicamente PDF, de una carpeta a otra.

Answer (score 0):

Trata de comentar esta línea:

```
f1 = new File(newPath+oldName);
```

Si no me equivoco, al hacer esa línea crea el archivo y luego cuando quieres mover el nombre, ha sido reservado para crear un archivo allí, entonces te da error.

Si tienes más dudas, lee el siguiente enlace:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html